# switch передача управления в обход инициализации

Tags: c++

Выдает ошибку на этом отрывке кода
[image: .]

```
 switch (f) {
            case '1':
                string Adata = "C:/MainProject/";
```

Comment: Ну да, нельзя. А вопрос в чем? "Кто виноват?" или "Что делать"?

Comment: в фигурные скобки нужно брать.

Comment: @KoVadim Это ответ на вопрос "Что делать?" :)